# how to know which column is matched when filter the records by multiple columns compare

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table "table1" like

```
NAME COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A    1    2    3    4
```

I want to filter the table by

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 where (COL1=1 OR COL2=1 OR COL3=1 OR COL4=1)"
```

I expect the result is

```
NAME COL_NAME
A    COL1
```

Is that possible by SQL statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not limited to selection of columns in your select list, you can use expressions. For example, you can use this:

```
SELECT
    NAME, -- More columns as needed
    CASE
    WHEN COL1=1 THEN 'COL1'
    WHEN COL2=1 THEN 'COL2'
    WHEN COL3=1 THEN 'COL3'
    WHEN COL4=1 THEN 'COL4'
    ELSE NULL END AS COL_MATCH
FROM table1 where (COL1=1 OR COL2=1 OR COL3=1 OR COL4=1)
```

Comment: Thank you ,dasblinkenlight!